# Use Google Sign In cookies to open an already signed in page (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cookies, puppeteer

What I want is to get a cookie and re-use it whenever I want to open an already signed in puppeteer instance. I tried this, but it didn't work:

Function which would get cookies:

```
async function writeCookies(page, cookiesPath) {
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    // This gets all cookies from all URLs, not just the current URL
    const cookies = (await client.send("Network.getAllCookies"))["cookies"];
    console.log(cookies)
    console.log("Saving", cookies.length, "cookies");
    // fs.writeFileSync(cookiesPath, JSON.stringify(cookies));
    console.log(cookiesPath)
    console.log(cookies)
    // await fs.writeJSON(cookiesPath, cookies);
  }
```

How I implemented it:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
time = new Date()
await page.goto("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession")
await page.$eval('#identifierId', (el) => (el.value = "test@gmail.com"));
await page.click("#identifierNext > div > button > div.VfPpkd-RLmnJb");
await page.waitForSelector('#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input', { visible: true });
await page.$eval('#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input', (el) => (el.value = "Tester"));
await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext > div > button > div.VfPpkd-RLmnJb', { visible: true });
await sleep(1000)
await page.click("#passwordNext > div > button > div.VfPpkd-RLmnJb");
writeCookies(page,"./WebHook.js")
```

How I would send the cookies:

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({cookies :`${cookies}`})
```

I also tried this way:

```
async function restoreCookies(page, cookiesPath) {
  try {
    // const cookies = await fs.readJSON(cookiesPath);
    let buf = fs.readFileSync(cookiesPath);
    let cookies = JSON.parse(buf);
    console.log("Loading", cookies.length, "cookies into browser");
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("restore cookie error", err);
  }
}
```

Maybe I am retrieving the wrong cookies.

Comment: You can use `userDataDir` argument of puppeteer to save cookies locally and then use it right? Something like `puppeteer.launch({ userDataDir: "./user_data" });`. This didn't work for you?

Comment: i used that before but dont work when i open run multiple instances of the same code

Comment: Hey, could you then update more specifically what is tried in the question and what's still an issue with the available solution?

Comment: I helped with a somewhat similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762024/how-to-login-to-gmail-using-reqeusts-in-node-js/66766864?noredirect=1#comment118139874_66766864). Not sure if that would help you but maybe take a look at how I created and set the cookies. If that doesn't work let me know and I can definitely try to help you out!

Comment: thank u that helped, the problem is that after some time it would sign out on it self and require to enter password, any how if you want to post the answer here so u can give u the bounty and the accepted answer