# how to login to gmail using reqeusts in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, gmail, puppeteer

so what i want to do is to login to gmail using requests or browser mode but requests is preferred so i can get the login cookies so when i want to login again using browser (puppeteer) i dont have to automate the process again i can just send the cookies i have to open an already signed in gmail account ,
i tried Getting SSID and HID cookies and sending them back but that didnt work

i was getting and sending cookies using this method

```
async function restoreCookies(page, cookiesPath) {
  try {
    // const cookies = await fs.readJSON(cookiesPath);
    let buf = fs.readFileSync(cookiesPath);
    let cookies = JSON.parse(buf);
    console.log("Loading", cookies.length, "cookies into browser");
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("restore cookie error", err);
  }
}
async function writeCookies(page, cookiesPath) {
  const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
  // This gets all cookies from all URLs, not just the current URL
  const cookies = (await client.send("Network.getAllCookies"))["cookies"];
  console.log(cookies)
  console.log("Saving", cookies.length, "cookies");
  // fs.writeFileSync(cookiesPath, JSON.stringify(cookies));
  console.log(cookiesPath)
  console.log(cookies)
  // await fs.writeJSON(cookiesPath, cookies);
}
```

and i tried this way

```
await page.setCookie(...setcookie);
```

am proably using the wrong cookies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've actually found a few different ways to solve this issue. The way I did this was using request interceptions to call my getCookies function and then storing those cookies. My setCookies function was called after my page was instantiated and before I send the page to my url.

### Solution 1:

```js
const getCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get all cookies
    const cookiesArray = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');

    // Get cookies from array
    const cookies = await cookiesArray.cookies;

    // Save cookies to file
    fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        return;
    });
}

const setCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get cookies from file
    let cookies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./cookies.json'));

    // Set page cookies
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    return
}
```

### Solution 2

```js
const getCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get page cookies
    const cookies = await page.cookies()

    // Save cookies to file
    fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        return
    });
}


const setCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get cookies from file as a string
    let cookiesString = fs.readFileSync('./cookies.json', 'utf8');

    // Parse string
    let cookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString)

    // Set page cookies
    await page.setCookie.apply(page, cookies);
    return
}
```

*Edit: You asked for more context on when the function is called so here's an example of how I use it.*

The way I use my function is after a user signs into their google account. I have a link such as [this](https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=wise&continue=https://youtube.com) that is meant to redirect to YouTube after a successful login. I setup my page to intercept requests, so whenever there is a request for YouTube, I call my `getCookies` function and then close the browser after it succeeds.

An example code block looks like this:

```js
// Create page once browser loads
let [page] = await browser.pages();

// Turn on page request interception
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

// Add event listener on request
page.on('request', async (req) => {

    // If the request url is what I want, start my function
    if (req.url() === 'https://youtube.com/?authuser=0') {
        await getCookies(page);
        await browser.close();
    }

    // If the url is not, continue normal functionality of the page
    req.continue();
});

// Then go to my url once all the listeners are setup
await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=wise&continue=https://youtube.com')
```

Comment: can i have more details where are u using the get cookies function, thank you

Comment: I've added an example to my answer, check it out and let me know if you need any help

Comment: My pleasure, glad to see it helped!