# how to stay signed in gmail using puppeteer(node js )

Tags: javascript, cookies, automation, gmail, puppeteer

so what i want to do is to open an already signed in gmail account, i used this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762024/how-to-login-to-gmail-using-reqeusts-in-node-js/66766864?noredirect=1#comment118139874_66766864) by [wolfy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15415297/wolfy) but the thing is that it would sign you out of the account after a while or when i open multiple instances with the same cookies  and u have to enter the password again

here how i did it

```
const getCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get all cookies
    const cookiesArray = await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies');

    // Get cookies from array
    const cookies = await cookiesArray.cookies;

    // Save cookies to file
    fs.writeFile('./cookies.json', JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        return;
    });
}

const setCookies = async (page) => {
    // Get cookies from file
    let cookies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./cookies.json'));

    // Set page cookies
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    return
}
```

how i sent cookies

```
// Create page once browser loads
let [page] = await browser.pages();

// Turn on page request interception
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

// Add event listener on request
page.on('request', async (req) => {

    // If the request url is what I want, start my function
    if (req.url() === 'https://youtube.com/?authuser=0') {
        await getCookies(page);
        await browser.close();
    }

    // If the url is not, continue normal functionality of the page
    req.continue();
});

// Then go to my url once all the listeners are setup
await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?service=wise&continue=https://youtube.com')
```

Comment: Saw this question and was about to say hey that looks familiar! When you say it signs you out after a while do you mean a certain time period? Or do you mean that if you load a browser with those cookies eventually it wont sign you in when you load the browser?

Comment: hi! , will i kept testing for a whole day to know how and why would it sign me out and it was just a random thing some times after a minute of two sometimes it would make 30 min , some times if i opened multiple instances it would be normal sometimes don't, Thank you

Comment: Interesting. I've never had that issue so I can't give you an example on how to fix it but I will try to replicate the issue so I can help. However, one thing I do that may help is: before I close any browser instance I get all the cookies and store them again since they have changed since the last time.

Comment: maybe that is one solution i would try , thank you man , if u would put it as an answer so i can reward you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we spoke about in the comments, I am going to try and replicate this issue to see if I can find a proper solution for you. However, one idea you can try is restoring the cookies before you close the browser each time. You can just call your `getCookies` method again and it should get the most updated version of your cookies (as they would have changed since the last time).

Comment: https://twitter.com/overflow_meme/status/1378026489204121601?s=20 LOL